# Не могу убрать с сайта Parse error: syntax error

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Движок Wordpress. После перевода двух слов на русский язык, заливал файлик на сервер. Редактировал при помощи программы Sublime Text 2. Выдало ошибку :

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in
>   /var/www/u0164453/public_html/sunnyge.com/wp-content/themes/BookYourTravel/single-accommodation.php
>   on line 1

В файле вернул всё на место, но ошибка не исчезает. Нашел исходный файл, залил на сервер, всё ровно не исчезает ошибка.

После того как файл из бекапа полежит на сервере (а скорее всего, после того как при обращении к этому файлу на сайте вылетит ошибка) - код в файле меняется (пропадают переносы строк):

```
<?php get_header();  BYT_Theme_Utils::breadcrumbs();get_sidebar('under-header');    global $post, $current_user, $accommodation_obj, $entity_obj, $score_out_of_10, $default_accommodation_tabs, $byt_accommodations_post_type, $byt_theme_of_custom;$enable_reviews = $byt_theme_globals->enable_reviews();$enable_accommodations = $byt_theme_globals->enable_accommodations();$accommodation_extra_fields = $byt_theme_globals->get_accommodation_extra_fields();$location_extra_fields = $byt_theme_globals->get_location_extra_fields();$tab_array = $byt_theme_globals->get_accommodation_tabs();$price_decimal_places = $byt_theme_globals->get_price_decimal_places();$default_currency_symbol = $byt_theme_globals->get_default_currency_symbol();$show_currency_symbol_after = $byt_theme_globals->show_currency_symbol_after();if ( have_posts() ) { the_post(); $accommodation_obj = new byt_accommodation($post);  $entity_obj = $accommodation_obj;   $accommodation_id = $accommodation_obj->get_id();   $base_accommodation_id = $accommodation_obj->get_base_id(); $accommodation_location = $accommodation_obj->get_location();   $is_self_catered = $accommodation_obj->get_is_self_catered();       $accommodation_latitude = $accommodation_obj->get_custom_field('latitude'); $accommodation_longitude = $accommodation_obj->get_custom_field('longitude');   $accommodation_count_children_stay_free = $accommodation_obj->get_count_children_stay_free();   $accommodation_is_price_per_person = $accommodation_obj->get_is_price_per_person(); $accommodation_is_reservation_only = $accommodation_obj->get_is_reservation_only();     $total_price_label = __('Total price', 'bookyourtravel');   if ($accommodation_is_price_per_person && $accommodation_count_children_stay_free > 0)      $total_price_label = sprintf(__('Total price (first %d children stay free)', 'bookyourtravel'), $accommodation_count_children_stay_free);               $max_count = $max_child_count = 0;      if ($is_self_catered) {     $max_count = $accommodation_obj->get_custom_field('max_count');     $max_count = isset($max_count) ? intval($max_count) : 5;        $max_child_count = $accommodation_obj->get_custom_field('max_child_count');     $max_child_count = isset($max_child_count) ? intval($max_child_count) : 5;  }   $min_days_stay = $accommodation_obj->get_custom_field('min_days_stay'); $min_days_stay = isset($min_days_stay) ? intval($min_days_stay) : 0;        $accommodation_check_in_time = $accommodation_obj->get_custom_field('check_in_time');   $accommodation_check_out_time = $accommodation_obj->get_custom_field('check_out_time');     $check_in_out_times = array();  $check_in_out_times[] = array('value' => '', 'label' => __('Flexible', 'bookyourtravel'));      for ($i=0; $i<24;$i++)      $check_in_out_times[] = array('value' => sprintf("%02s:00", $i), 'label' => sprintf("%02s:00", $i));        $check_in_time = $accommodation_check_in_time == '' ? __('Flexible', 'bookyourtravel') : $accommodation_check_in_time;  $check_out_time = $accommodation_check_out_time == '' ? __('Flexible', 'bookyourtravel') : $accommodation_check_out_time;       // include various forms (booking, review, confirmation)    if ($enable_reviews) {      get_template_part('includes/parts/review', 'form');     }   ?>  <script>        window.postType = 'accommodation';  </script>   <?php   get_template_part('includes/parts/inquiry', 'form');    ?>      <!--accommodation three-fourth content-->   <section class="three-fourth">  <?php   get_template_part('includes/parts/accommodation', 'booking-form');  get_template_part('includes/parts/accommodation', 'confirmation-form'); ?>      <script>                window.minDaysStayError = <?php echo json_encode(sprintf(__('Accommodation requires %d minimum days stay!', 'bookyourtravel'), $min_days_stay)); ?>;        window.formSingleError = <?php echo json_encode(__('You failed to provide 1 field. It has been highlighted below.', 'bookyourtravel')); ?>;     window.formMultipleError = <?php echo json_encode(__('You failed to provide {0} fields. They have been highlighted below.', 'bookyourtravel'));  ?>;        window.accommodationId = <?php echo $base_accommodation_id; ?>;     window.roomTypeId = 0;      window.accommodationIsSelfCatered = <?php echo $is_self_catered; ?>;        window.accommodationIsReservationOnly = <?php echo $accommodation_is_reservation_only; ?>;      window.accommodationIsPricePerPerson = <?php echo $accommodation_is_price_per_person; ?>;       window.accommodationCountChildrenStayFree = <?php echo $accommodation_count_children_stay_free; ?>;     <?php if ($is_self_catered) { ?>        window.accommodationMaxCount =  <?php echo $max_count; ?>;      window.accommodationMaxChildCount = <?php echo $max_child_count; ?>;        <?php } ?>      window.accommodationMinDaysStay = <?php echo $min_days_stay; ?>;        window.entityLatitude = <?php echo json_encode($accommodation_latitude); ?>;        window.entityLongitude = <?php echo json_encode($accommodation_longitude); ?>;      window.entityInfoboxText = <?php echo json_encode('<strong>' . $accommodation_obj->get_title() . '</strong><br />' . $accommodation_obj->get_custom_field('address') . '<br />' . $accommodation_obj->get_custom_field('website_address')); ?>;     window.currentMonth = <?php echo date('n'); ?>;     window.currentYear = <?php echo date('Y'); ?>;      window.adultCountLabel = <?php echo json_encode(__('Adults', 'bookyourtravel')); ?>;        window.pricePerAdultLabel = <?php echo json_encode(__('Price per adult', 'bookyourtravel')); ?>;        window.childCountLabel = <?php echo json_encode(__('Children', 'bookyourtravel')); ?>;      window.pricePerChildLabel = <?php echo json_encode(__('Price per child', 'bookyourtravel')); ?>;        window.pricePerDayLabel = <?php echo json_encode(__('Price per day', 'bookyourtravel')); ?>;        window.priceTotalLabel = <?php echo json_encode($total_price_label); ?>;        window.dateLabel = <?php echo json_encode(__('Date', 'bookyourtravel')); ?>;    </script>   <?php $accommodation_obj->render_image_gallery(); ?>    <!--inner navigation--> <nav class="inner-nav">     <ul>            <?php           do_action( 'byt_show_single_accommodation_tab_items_before' );          $first_display_tab = '';                        $i = 0;         if (is_array($tab_array) && count($tab_array) > 0) {                foreach ($tab_array as $tab) {                                  if (!isset($tab['hide']) || $tab['hide'] != '1') {                                          $tab_label = '';                        if (isset($tab['label'])) {                         $tab_label = $tab['label'];                         $tab_label = $byt_theme_of_custom->get_translated_dynamic_string($byt_theme_of_custom->get_option_id_context('accommodation_tabs') . ' ' . $tab['label'], $tab_label);                      }                                           if($i==0)                           $first_display_tab = $tab['id'];                        if ($tab['id'] == 'reviews' && $enable_reviews) {                           BYT_Theme_Utils::render_tab("accommodation", $tab['id'], '',  '<a href="#' . $tab['id'] . '" title="' . $tab_label . '">' . $tab_label . '</a>');                       } elseif ($tab['id'] == 'location' && !empty($accommodation_latitude) && !empty($accommodation_longitude)) {                            BYT_Theme_Utils::render_tab("accommodation", $tab['id'], '',  '<a href="#' . $tab['id'] . '" title="' . $tab_label . '">' . $tab_label . '</a>');                       } elseif ($tab['id'] == 'things-to-do' && isset($accommodation_location)) {                         BYT_Theme_Utils::render_tab("accommodation", $tab['id'], '',  '<a href="#' . $tab['id'] . '" title="' . $tab_label . '">' . $tab_label . '</a>');                       } elseif ($tab['id'] == 'description' || $tab['id'] == 'availability' || $tab['id'] == 'facilities') {                          BYT_Theme_Utils::render_tab("tour", $tab['id'], '',  '<a href="#' . $tab['id'] . '" title="' . $tab_label . '">' . $tab_label . '</a>');                        } else {                                                    $all_empty_fields = BYT_Theme_Utils::are_tab_fields_empty('accommodation_extra_fields', $accommodation_extra_fields, $tab['id'], $accommodation_obj);                                                       if (!$all_empty_fields) {                               BYT_Theme_Utils::render_tab("accommodation", $tab['id'], '',  '<a href="#' . $tab['id'] . '" title="' . $tab_label . '">' . $tab_label . '</a>');                           }                       }                                               $i++;                   }               }           }                       do_action( 'byt_show_single_accommodation_tab_items_after' );           ?>      </ul>   </nav>  <!--//inner navigation-->   <?php do_action( 'byt_show_single_accommodation_tab_content_before' ); ?>   <script>        window.moreInfoText = '<?php echo __('+ more info', 'bookyourtravel'); ?>';     window.lessInfoText = '<?php echo __('+ less info', 'bookyourtravel'); ?>'; </script>   <section id="availability" class="tab-content <?php echo $first_display_tab == 'availability' ? 'initial' : ''; ?>">        <article>           <?php do_action( 'byt_show_single_accommodation_availability_before' ); ?>          <h1><?php _e('Availability', 'bookyourtravel'); ?></h1>         <?php           BYT_Theme_Utils::render_field("text-wrap", "", "", $accommodation_obj->get_custom_field('availability_text'), '', false, true);         $room_type_ids = $accommodation_obj->get_room_types();          if ($room_type_ids && count($room_type_ids) > 0) { ?>           <ul class="room-types">             <?php               // Loop through the items returned                              for ( $z = 0; $z < count($room_type_ids); $z++ ) {                  $room_type_id = $room_type_ids[$z];                 $room_type_obj = new byt_room_type(intval($room_type_id));                  $room_type_min_price = $byt_accommodations_post_type->get_accommodation_min_price($accommodation_id, $room_type_id);                ?>              <!--room_type-->                <li id="room_type_<?php echo $room_type_id; ?>">                    <div class="row">                       <?php if ($room_type_obj->get_main_image('medium')) { ?>                        <figure class="left"><img src="<?php echo esc_url($room_type_obj->get_main_image('medium')) ?>" alt="<?php echo $room_type_obj->get_title() ?>" /><a href="<?php echo esc_url($room_type_obj->get_main_image()); ?>" class="image-overlay" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]"></a></figure>                        <?php } ?>                      <div class="meta room_type">                            <h2><?php echo $room_type_obj->get_title(); ?></h2>                         <?php BYT_Theme_Utils::render_field('', '', '', $room_type_obj->get_custom_field('meta'), '', true, true); ?>                           <?php BYT_Theme_Utils::render_link_button("#", "more-info", "", __('+ more info', 'bookyourtravel')); ?>                        </div>                      <div class="room-information">                          <div class="row">                               <span class="first"><?php _e('Max:', 'bookyourtravel'); ?></span>                               <span class="second">                                   <?php for ( $j = 0; $j < $room_type_obj->get_custom_field('max_count'); $j++ ) { ?>                                 <img src="<?php echo BYT_Theme_Utils::get_file_uri('/images/ico/person.png'); ?>" alt="" />                                 <?php } ?>                              </span>                         </div>                          <?php if ($room_type_min_price > 0) { ?>                            <div class="row">                               <span class="first"><?php _e('Price from:', 'bookyourtravel'); ?></span>                                <div class="second price">                                  <em>                                        <?php if (!$show_currency_symbol_after) { ?>                                        <span class="curr"><?php echo $default_currency_symbol; ?></span>                                       <span class="amount"><?php echo number_format_i18n( $room_type_min_price, $price_decimal_places ); ?></span>                                        <?php } else { ?>                                       <span class="amount"><?php echo number_format_i18n( $room_type_min_price, $price_decimal_places ); ?></span>                                        <span class="curr"><?php echo $default_currency_symbol; ?></span>                                       <?php } ?>                                  </em>                                   <input type="hidden" class="max_count" value="<?php echo esc_attr($room_type_obj->get_custom_field('max_count')); ?>" />                                    <input type="hidden" class="max_child_count" value="<?php echo esc_attr($room_type_obj->get_custom_field('max_child_count')); ?>" />                                </div>                          </div>                          <?php BYT_Theme_Utils::render_link_button("#", "gradient-button book-accommodation-select-dates", "book-accommodation-$room_type_id", __('Select dates', 'bookyourtravel')); ?>                         <?php } ?>                      </div>                      <div class="more-information">                          <?php BYT_Theme_Utils::render_field('', '', __('Room facilities:', 'bookyourtravel'), $room_type_obj->get_facilities_string(), '', true, true); ?>                          <?php echo $room_type_obj->get_description(); ?>                            <?php BYT_Theme_Utils::render_field('', '', __('Bed size:', 'bookyourtravel'), $room_type_obj->get_custom_field('bed_size'), '', true, true); ?>                            <?php BYT_Theme_Utils::render_field('', '', __('Room size:', 'bookyourtravel'), $room_type_obj->get_custom_field('room_size'), '', true, true); ?>                      </div>                  </div>                  <div class="step1_controls" style="display:none"></div>             </li>               <!--//room-->               <?php               }               // Reset Second Loop Post Data              wp_reset_postdata();                // end while ?>         </ul>               <?php } else if ($accommodation_obj->get_is_self_catered()) {               $accommodation_min_price = $byt_accommodations_post_type->get_accommodation_min_price($accommodation_id, 0);                if ($accommodation_min_price > 0) {             ?>              <div class="step1_controls" style="display:none"></div>             <?php               } else {                    echo '<p>' . __('We are sorry, this accommodation is not available to book at the moment', 'bookyourtravel') . '</p>';              }           } else {                BYT_Theme_Utils::render_field('text-wrap', '', '', __('We are sorry, there are no rooms available at this accommodation at the moment', 'bookyourtravel'), '', true, true);         } ?>            <?php BYT_Theme_Utils::render_tab_extra_fields('accommodation_extra_fields', $accommodation_extra_fields, 'availability', $accommodation_obj); ?>           <?php do_action( 'byt_show_single_accommodation_availability_after' ); ?>       </article>  </section>      <!--description-->  <section id="description" class="tab-content <?php echo $first_display_tab == 'description' ? 'initial' : ''; ?>">      <article>                   <?php           do_action( 'byt_show_single_accommodation_description_before' );            BYT_Theme_Utils::render_field("text-wrap", "", "", $accommodation_obj->get_description(), __('General', 'bookyourtravel'), false, false, false);            BYT_Theme_Utils::render_field("text-wrap", "", "", $check_in_time, __('Check-in time', 'bookyourtravel'), false, false, false);         BYT_Theme_Utils::render_field("text-wrap", "", "", $check_out_time, __('Check-out time', 'bookyourtravel'), false, false, false);           BYT_Theme_Utils::render_tab_extra_fields('accommodation_extra_fields', $accommodation_extra_fields, 'description', $accommodation_obj);         do_action( 'byt_show_single_accommodation_description_after' );             ?>      </article>  </section>  <!--//description-->        <!--facilities-->   <section id="facilities" class="tab-content <?php echo $first_display_tab == 'facilities' ? 'initial' : ''; ?>">        <article>           <?php do_action( 'byt_show_single_accommodation_facilites_before' ); ?>         <?php           $facilities = $accommodation_obj->get_facilities();         if ($facilities && count($facilities) > 0) { ?>         <h1><?php _e('Facilities', 'bookyourtravel'); ?></h1>           <div class="text-wrap">                 <ul class="three-col">              <?php               for( $i = 0; $i < count($facilities); $i++) {                   $accommodation_facility = $facilities[$i];                  echo '<li>' . $accommodation_facility->name  . '</li>';             } ?>                                    </ul>           </div>          <?php } // endif (!empty($accommodation_facilities)) ?>                     <?php BYT_Theme_Utils::render_tab_extra_fields('accommodation_extra_fields', $accommodation_extra_fields, 'facilities', $accommodation_obj); ?>                     <?php do_action( 'byt_show_single_accommodation_facilites_after' ); ?>      </article>  </section>  <!--//facilities--> <?php if ((!empty($accommodation_latitude)) && (!empty($accommodation_longitude))) { ?> <!--location--> <section id="location" class="tab-content <?php echo $first_display_tab == 'location' ? 'active' : ''; ?>">     <article>           <?php do_action( 'byt_show_single_accommodation_location_before' ); ?>          <!--map--><div class="gmap" id="map_canvas"></div><!--//map-->          <?php BYT_Theme_Utils::render_tab_extra_fields('accommodation_extra_fields', $accommodation_extra_fields, 'location', $accommodation_obj); ?>                       <?php do_action( 'byt_show_single_accommodation_location_after' ); ?>       </article>  </section>  <!--//location-->   <?php }  ?> <?php if ($enable_reviews) { ?> <!--reviews-->  <section id="reviews" class="tab-content <?php echo $first_display_tab == 'review' ? 'initial' : ''; ?>">       <?php       do_action( 'byt_show_single_accommodation_reviews_before' );        get_template_part('includes/parts/review', 'item');         BYT_Theme_Utils::render_tab_extra_fields('accommodation_extra_fields', $accommodation_extra_fields, 'reviews', $accommodation_obj);         do_action( 'byt_show_single_accommodation_reviews_after' );         ?>  </section>  <!--//reviews-->        <?php } // if ($enable_reviews) ?>  <?php   if ($accommodation_location != null) { ?>   <!--things to do--> <section id="things-to-do" class="tab-content <?php echo $first_display_tab == 'things-to-do' ? 'initial' : ''; ?>">        <article>           <?php do_action( 'byt_show_single_accommodation_location_before' ); ?>          <?php                               $sports_and_nature_field = BYT_Theme_Utils::find_extra_field($location_extra_fields, 'sports_and_nature');              $culture_and_history_field = BYT_Theme_Utils::find_extra_field($location_extra_fields, 'culture_and_history');              $nightlife_field = BYT_Theme_Utils::find_extra_field($location_extra_fields, 'nightlife');                              $sports_and_nature_field_label = __('Sports and nature', 'bookyourtravel');             if (isset($sports_and_nature_field) && isset($sports_and_nature_field['label'])) {                  $sports_and_nature_field_label = $sports_and_nature_field['label'];                 $sports_and_nature_field_label = $byt_theme_of_custom->get_translated_dynamic_string($byt_theme_of_custom->get_option_id_context('location_extra_fields') . ' ' . $sports_and_nature_field_label, $sports_and_nature_field_label);              }                               $culture_and_history_field_label = __('Culture &amp; history', 'bookyourtravel');               if (isset($culture_and_history_field) && isset($culture_and_history_field['label'])) {                  $culture_and_history_field_label = $culture_and_history_field['label'];                 $culture_and_history_field_label = $byt_theme_of_custom->get_translated_dynamic_string($byt_theme_of_custom->get_option_id_context('location_extra_fields') . ' ' . $culture_and_history_field_label, $culture_and_history_field_label);                }                               $nightlife_field_label = __('Nightlife', 'bookyourtravel');             if (isset($nightlife_field) && isset($nightlife_field['label'])) {                  $nightlife_field_label = $nightlife_field['label'];                 $nightlife_field_label = $byt_theme_of_custom->get_translated_dynamic_string($byt_theme_of_custom->get_option_id_context('location_extra_fields') . ' ' . $nightlife_field_label, $nightlife_field_label);              }                           BYT_Theme_Utils::render_field("", "", "", BYT_Theme_Utils::render_image('', '', $accommodation_location->get_main_image(), $accommodation_location->get_title(), $accommodation_location->get_title(), false) . $accommodation_location->get_excerpt(), $accommodation_location->get_title());              BYT_Theme_Utils::render_field("", "", "", BYT_Theme_Utils::render_image('', '', $accommodation_location->get_custom_field_image_uri('sports_and_nature_image', 'medium'), $sports_and_nature_field_label, $sports_and_nature_field_label, false) . $accommodation_location->get_custom_field('sports_and_nature'), $sports_and_nature_field_label);             BYT_Theme_Utils::render_field("", "", "", BYT_Theme_Utils::render_image('', '', $accommodation_location->get_custom_field_image_uri('nightlife_image', 'medium'), $nightlife_field_label, $nightlife_field_label, false) . $accommodation_location->get_custom_field('nightlife'), $nightlife_field_label);             BYT_Theme_Utils::render_field("", "", "", BYT_Theme_Utils::render_image('', '', $accommodation_location->get_custom_field_image_uri('culture_and_history_image', 'medium'), $culture_and_history_field_label, $culture_and_history_field_label, false) . $accommodation_location->get_custom_field('culture_and_history'), $culture_and_history_field_label);           ?>          <hr />          <?php BYT_Theme_Utils::render_link_button(get_permalink($accommodation_location->get_id()), "gradient-button right", "", __('Read more', 'bookyourtravel')); ?>         <?php BYT_Theme_Utils::render_tab_extra_fields('accommodation_extra_fields', $accommodation_extra_fields, 'things-to-do', $accommodation_obj); ?>                       <?php do_action( 'byt_show_single_accommodation_location_after' ); ?>       </article>  </section>  <!--//things-to-do-->   <?php } ?>  <?php   foreach ($tab_array as $tab) {      if (count(BYT_Theme_Utils::custom_array_search($default_accommodation_tabs, 'id', $tab['id'])) == 0) {                  $all_empty_fields = BYT_Theme_Utils::are_tab_fields_empty('accommodation_extra_fields', $accommodation_extra_fields, $tab['id'], $accommodation_obj);                       if (!$all_empty_fields) {       ?>          <section id="<?php echo esc_attr($tab['id']); ?>" class="tab-content <?php echo ($first_display_tab == $tab['id'] ? 'initial' : ''); ?>">               <article>                   <?php do_action( 'byt_show_single_accommodation_' . $tab['id'] . '_before' ); ?>                    <?php BYT_Theme_Utils::render_tab_extra_fields('accommodation_extra_fields', $accommodation_extra_fields, $tab['id'], $accommodation_obj); ?>                               <?php do_action( 'byt_show_single_accommodation_' . $tab['id'] . '_after' ); ?>             </article>          </section>      <?php           }       }   }       do_action( 'byt_show_single_accommodation_tab_content_after' ); ?>  </section>  <!--//accommodation content-->  <?php   get_sidebar('right-accommodation'); } // end if?><div class="step1_controls_holder" style="display:none">   <div class="row calendar">      <div class="f-item">            <label><?php _e('Select booking dates:', 'bookyourtravel') ?></label>           <div class="datepicker_holder"></div>       </div>  </div>  <div class="row loading" id="datepicker_loading" style="display:none">      <div class="ball"></div>        <div class="ball1"></div>   </div>  <div class="error step1_error" style="display:none;"><div><p></p></div></div>   <div class="row twins">     <div class="f-item dates_row dates_row_from" style="display:none">          <label><?php _e('Check-in', 'bookyourtravel') ?></label>            <span id="date_from_text"></span>           <input type="hidden" name="selected_date_from" id="selected_date_from" value="" />          <?php if (!empty($accommodation_check_in_time)) { echo ' ' . $accommodation_check_in_time; } ?>     </div>      <div class="f-item dates_row dates_row_to" style="display:none">            <label><?php _e('Check out', 'bookyourtravel') ?></label>           <span id="date_to_text"></span>         <input type="hidden" name="selected_date_to" id="selected_date_to" value="" />          <?php if (!empty($accommodation_check_out_time)) { echo ' ' . $accommodation_check_out_time; } ?>       </div>  </div>  <div class="row twins bf_room_type_row" style="display:none">       <div class="f-item">            <label for="booking_form_adults"><?php _e('Adults', 'bookyourtravel') ?></label>            <select class="dynamic_control" id="booking_form_adults" name="booking_form_adults"></select>       </div>      <div class="f-item booking_form_children">          <label for="booking_form_children"><?php _e('Children', 'bookyourtravel') ?></label>            <select class="dynamic_control" id="booking_form_children" name="booking_form_children"></select>       </div>  </div>  <div class="row bf_room_type_row" style="display:none">     <div class="f-item bf_room_type_cell">          <label><?php _e('Room type', 'bookyourtravel') ?></label>           <span id="room_type"></span>            <input type="hidden" name="room_type_id" id="room_type_id" />       </div>  </div>  <div class="row price_row" style="display:none">        <div class="f-item">            <table class="breakdown tablesorter responsive">                <thead></thead>             <tfoot></tfoot>             <tbody></tbody>         </table>        </div>  </div>  <div class='booking-commands'>  <?php   BYT_Theme_Utils::render_link_button("#", "gradient-button book-accommodation-reset", "book-accommodation-rest", __('Reset', 'bookyourtravel')); BYT_Theme_Utils::render_link_button("#", "gradient-button book-accommodation-next", "book-accommodation-next", __('Proceed', 'bookyourtravel'));    ?>  </div></div><?phpget_footer();
```

Comment: У вас ошибка с расстановкой фигурных скобок, вы выкладываете только половину кода. Высока вероятность, что ответ заминусуют.

Comment: Добавил код полностью

Comment: Это содержимое файла single-accommodation.php? В нем совпадает количество открывающихся и закрывающихся фигурных кавычек. Куда этот файл включается, главное какие изменения вы вносили? Есть возможность сравнить код через diff?

Comment: Да, изменения я делал в этом файле, но при чём тут это? Если я заливаю на сервер файл из самого первого бэкапа.

Comment: Количество фигурных кавычек равное (по 39 штук).

Comment: Это точно не тот файл. Внимательно проверяйте путь к файлу. Смотрите что в первой строке. Где-то должна быть закрывающая фгурная скобка. Чудес не бывает.

Comment: Кстати ошибка выводится в браузер или вы смотрите в логи?

Comment: @tutankhamun в браузере смотрю

Comment: Почему то после того как файл полежит на сервере, он становиться без переносов, весь код написан в одну строчку. Наверное по этому ошибка выдаётся на линии 1.

Comment: Наверное поэтому. А ошибка в браузере может быть кешированной. Выкачайте файл и добавьте в вопрос тот, который был на сервере

Comment: Добавил, посмотрите пожалуйста.

Comment: Ну вот тут явно есть лишняя скобка после `get_sidebar('right-accommodation');` Но правильно будет если ее убрать или нужно где-то скобку открыть - это надо смотреть более детально

Comment: А это может быть из-за <?phpget_footer(); в самом конце. там нет пробела

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка была в настройках моей FileZilla. Файл закачивался не правильно - терялись фрагменты кода. Видимо Настройки передачи как то не подходили под сервер. Закинул файл через другой файлообменник и всё получилось. Всем спасибо за помощь.